# PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField Rendering not working

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, publishing-site

i am using site content type RichHtmlField as Full HTML type with value = hello PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField tag in layoutpage does not render it.

Instead of displaying hello. it is displaying html tags.

Any help wold b appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please give us the code that you use the set the value of your field? Also can you please show the HTML it renders and how you wire up the control in the mark-up